# How do I add my own Certificate Authority to my Android device?

Tags: android, ssl, certificate-authority

I want to access my https site running on my local machine from my Android device on the same network.  Service workers and push notifications means I need to use https.

I have created my own CA + key, created certificates for `localhost` and `192.168.178.23`, and installed the CA on OSX.  This all works as expected - everything is green if I point my browser on my local machine at `localhost` and `192.168.178.23:3000`.  I followed [this guide](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec/).

Now I want to do the same for my Android device, so that I can access the local dev site over the network.

I put `myCA.crt` on my device and tap on it, but it says 'Private key required to install a certificate'.  The same happens when I navigate through the settings to `Install a certificate -> CA certificate`.

I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60245550/614523) to convert it into a `p12` file with both the key and the certificate combined.  (I'm not sure why Android needs the key here).  My command was `openssl pkcs12 -export -in myCA.crt -inkey myCA.key -out test-combined.p12`.

Now I move my `p12` file to my device and tap it.  It prompts for the password, and recognises that this has a key, but it won't let me put the certificate as a certificate authority - only as a "VPN and app user certificate" or a "Wifi certificate".  When I attempt to install the certificate via the settings, it allows me the unlock the file using the password but then says "this file can't be used as a CA certificate".

`myCA.key` is

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,A868E9FC78768599

axC3F...........................................................
.............stuff..............................................
...........................................................QBkMn
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

`myCA.crt` is

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIC9DCCAdwCCQDIK...............................................
......................... stuff ................................
................................................oLBZA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I'm a newbie with this stuff.  What am I missing?  This is Android 11.

Comment: In my case I could work around the issue using ngrok.  This doesn't answer the question, but perhaps this gets you moving too if you happen to read this.