# self signed certificate error on electron js

Tags: node.js, electron

I am making an app for my own use, when I try to post JSON to my PHP server at example.com, I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: self signed certificate error

I tried the following code and it works:

```
process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0
```

but I believe this approach is dangerous. What is the safe way to solve this error? I tried googling but did not find anything useful or maybe because I am a beginner I did not understand it.

Comment: please post the code which covers the request.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your self signed cert is on example.com and wherever your posting from doesn't trust it.

You may want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57565665/one-self-signed-cert-to-rule-them-all-chrome-android-and-ios) for how to create and use self signed certs from iOS, Android, and a browser.