# How to correctly a configure a self signed certificate for a test site served over localhost with multiple SANs?

Tags: android, ssl, openssl, certificate

I have a small test website that I'm trying to serve over https to an Android emulator on a webview. I've been generating self signed certs on my machine and importing them into my emulator's certificate store but I keep getting invalid common name errors when I load the page on the webview.

Because Android emulators exist behind a virtual firewall, they don't have access to the same network interfaces that the development machine does. I can't just load localhost from the emulator and have it go to the 127.0.0.1 loopback address. Instead, it is aliased as 10.0.2.2 on the emulator.

When I create the self signed cert, in the configuration file (as instructed from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57565665/one-self-signed-cert-to-rule-them-all-chrome-android-and-ios) question), I set the domain to localhost and set 10.0.2.2 as a SAN, but I still am not able to correctly load the https version of the website from my emulator. What might I be doing wrong?

My partial cnf file (Taken mostly from the top answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57565665/one-self-signed-cert-to-rule-them-all-chrome-android-and-ios) question):

```
...

[ subject ]
...
commonName              = localhost
emailAddress            = me@home.com

...

[ req_ext ]
subjectKeyIdentifier        = hash
basicConstraints        = CA:FALSE
keyUsage            = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName          = @alternate_names
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

[ alternate_names ]
DNS.1       = 127.0.0.1
DNS.2       = 10.0.2.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I ended up solving this problem was a bit of a hack. I added a new subdomain to my corp's public DNS and reverse proxied it to 127.0.0.1 and replaced the CN in the cert with the new domain.

Eg New domain - abc.xyz-corp.com. When my emulator tries to access that domain, it'll go to the corp's dns and be sent to 127.0.0.1 and resolve to the webapp hosted there.