# "Trust anchor for certification path not found." in a .NET Maui Project trying to contact a local .NET WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin, ssl-certificate, maui

I'm new to mobile development and I'm trying to have my .NET Maui app connect to a local ASP.NET Core website (API).

I am currently blocked by this exception:

`System.Net.WebException: 'java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.'`

I have followed this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/connect-to-local-web-services#bypass-the-certificate-security-check

Running `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` returns `A valid HTTPS certificate is already present.`

My current code is:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) =>
  {
     if (cert.Issuer.Equals("CN=localhost"))
          return true;
     return errors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None;
  };

var httpclient = new HttpClient(handler);
var test = await httpclient.PostAsync($"https://10.0.2.2:44393/" + uri, new StringContent(serializedItem, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

But the thing is that i never enter the ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback.

I also tried

```
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
        {
            return true;
        };
```

But no luck with that either.

Did something change in .NET MAUI?

Answer (score 9):

I encountered exactly the same problem when I was trying to get SignalR client to connect my local test server. After digging into the source code, I found that [`HttpClientHandler` actually uses `AndroidMessageHandler` as its underlying handler](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/65008a9df04166c1f6f84273cecd2025ab840eef/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClientHandler.AnyMobile.InvokeNativeHandler.cs).

While `AndroidMessageHandler` implements a `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` property, its value is [never used](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/0583ca1d3a44f4ffc6a29b487ef2b4ed33d2c067/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidMessageHandler.cs#L160) when sending requests. This issue is addressed in [this pull request](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/6665).

For now, to disable server certificate verification on Android, you can implement a custom `TrustProvider` which will bypass any certificate verification:

```cs
using Java.Net;
using Java.Security;
using Java.Security.Cert;
using Javax.Net.Ssl;

namespace MyApp.Platforms.Android
{
    internal class DangerousTrustProvider : Provider
    {
        private const string TRUST_PROVIDER_ALG = "DangerousTrustAlgorithm";
        private const string TRUST_PROVIDER_ID = "DangerousTrustProvider";

        public DangerousTrustProvider() : base(TRUST_PROVIDER_ID, 1, string.Empty)
        {
            var key = "TrustManagerFactory." + DangerousTrustManagerFactory.GetAlgorithm();
            var val = Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(DangerousTrustManagerFactory)).Name;
            Put(key, val);
        }

        public static void Register()
        {
            Provider registered = Security.GetProvider(TRUST_PROVIDER_ID);
            if (null == registered)
            {
                Security.InsertProviderAt(new DangerousTrustProvider(), 1);
                Security.SetProperty("ssl.TrustManagerFactory.algorithm", TRUST_PROVIDER_ALG);
            }
        }

        public class DangerousTrustManager : X509ExtendedTrustManager
        {
            public override void CheckClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, string authType, Socket socket) { }

            public override void CheckClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, string authType, SSLEngine engine) { }

            public override void CheckClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, string authType) { }

            public override void CheckServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, string authType, Socket socket) { }

            public override void CheckServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, string authType, SSLEngine engine) { }

            public override void CheckServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, string authType) { }

            public override X509Certificate[] GetAcceptedIssuers() => Array.Empty<X509Certificate>();
        }

        public class DangerousTrustManagerFactory : TrustManagerFactorySpi
        {
            protected override void EngineInit(IManagerFactoryParameters mgrparams) { }

            protected override void EngineInit(KeyStore keystore) { }

            protected override ITrustManager[] EngineGetTrustManagers() => new ITrustManager[] { new DangerousTrustManager() };

            public static string GetAlgorithm() => TRUST_PROVIDER_ALG;
        }
    }
}
```

If you also want to disable host name verfication, you'll need to dynamically inherit from `AndroidMessageHandler` and override its internal `GetSSLHostnameVerifier` method, to return a dummy `IHostNameVerifier`:

```cs
using Javax.Net.Ssl;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using Xamarin.Android.Net;

namespace MyApp.Platforms.Android
{
    static class DangerousAndroidMessageHandlerEmitter
    {
        private static Assembly _emittedAssembly = null;

        public static void Register(string handlerTypeName = "DangerousAndroidMessageHandler", string assemblyName = "DangerousAndroidMessageHandler")
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Name == assemblyName)
                {
                    if (_emittedAssembly == null)
                    {
                        _emittedAssembly = Emit(handlerTypeName, assemblyName);
                    }

                    return _emittedAssembly;
                }
                return null;
            };
        }

        private static AssemblyBuilder Emit(string handlerTypeName, string assemblyName)
        {
            var assembly = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName(assemblyName), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            var module = assembly.DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName);

            DefineDangerousAndroidMessageHandler(module, handlerTypeName);

            return assembly;
        }

        private static void DefineDangerousAndroidMessageHandler(ModuleBuilder module, string handlerTypeName)
        {
            var typeBuilder = module.DefineType(handlerTypeName, TypeAttributes.Public);
            typeBuilder.SetParent(typeof(AndroidMessageHandler));
            typeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);

            var methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
                "GetSSLHostnameVerifier",
                MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual,
                typeof(IHostnameVerifier),
                new[] { typeof(HttpsURLConnection) }
            );

            var generator = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(DangerousHostNameVerifier).GetMethod("Create"));
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            typeBuilder.CreateType();
        }
    }

    public class DangerousHostNameVerifier : Java.Lang.Object, IHostnameVerifier
    {
        public bool Verify(string hostname, ISSLSession session)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public static IHostnameVerifier Create() => new DangerousHostNameVerifier();
    }
}
```

Call `DangerousAndroidMessageHandlerEmitter.Register` and `DangerousTrustProvider` in your `MauiProgram`:

```cs
#if ANDROID && DEBUG
Platforms.Android.DangerousAndroidMessageHandlerEmitter.Register();
Platforms.Android.DangerousTrustProvider.Register();
#endif
```

One last step, you need to tell Xamarin to use your dynamically generated `DangerousAndroidMessageHandler`. You should be able to do so by setting `AndroidHttpClientHandlerType` to fully-qualified name of the handler type in your `csproj` file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>DangerousAndroidMessageHandler, DangerousAndroidMessageHandler</AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Or set Android runtime environment variable `XA_HTTP_CLIENT_HANDLER_TYPE` to the name of the handler:

```
XA_HTTP_CLIENT_HANDLER_TYPE=DangerousAndroidMessageHandler, DangerousAndroidMessageHandler
```

The above workaround will also work for `ClientWebSocket` and anything else using `SslStream`. Which means you can connect to your test SignalR server with   the WebSocket transport (which is what I was trying to achieve).

Just remember, **DO THIS ONLY IN DEBUG BUILDS**.

Comment: Using latest MAUI (VS 17.2 Preview 2.1 as of today), I kept getting `[X509Util] Error creating trust manager (crc64e2862aff4a97f0b0.DangerousTrustProvider_DangerousTrustManager): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required method checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[], String, String, String) missing
[X509Util] Could not find suitable trust manager` which is weird as there's no such method with 3 string parameters documented - *anywhere*! Turns out, changing `TrustManagerFactory` (see `var key` & `Security.SetProperty` lines above) to `DangerousTrustManagerFactory` solved that. 

Comment: DangerousTrustProvider has a heap of missing dependancies, couldnt spot them in NUGET, where do we get these usings from?

using Java.Net;
using Java.Security;
using Java.Security.Cert;
using Javax.Net.Ssl;

Comment: @devonuto You need to create a .NET MAUI project & select `net6.0-android` as compile target from the toolbar menu drop-down. Then, MAUI / Visual Studio will properly resolve them, no need to install any NuGet package - see my own answer for a full how-to.

Comment: @noelex Thank you!! This worked perfectly for me in .NET7 rc2.

Comment: Thank you so much! this helped me a lot for debugging my chromecast app to a physical device on my network. Do you have a solution for iOS? :)

Comment: Could not resolve 'DangerousAndroidMessageHandler'. Please check your `AndroidHttpClientHandlerType` setting. Why I get this error when I'm build the app?

Answer (score 4):

### The issue

As [nolex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/849642/noelex) already pointed out in his answer, the `HttpClientHandler` [actually uses](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/65008a9df04166c1f6f84273cecd2025ab840eef/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClientHandler.AnyMobile.InvokeNativeHandler.cs) `AndroidMessageHandler` as its underlying handler - which *does* implemented the known `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback`.
However, its value is [never used](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/0583ca1d3a44f4ffc6a29b487ef2b4ed33d2c067/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidMessageHandler.cs#L160) when sending requests which you can easily verify yourself by searching the linked source code file for another occurrence of that property.

There's even a [pull request](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/6665) waiting for (further) approval & merge since [February 11th this year](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/6665#issuecomment-1036462437) to solve this. But even after the [latest resolve](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/6665#issuecomment-1068224846) just 17 days ago as of today, it's still not merged. Plus, 5 checks are failing now - again.

### The only workaround - for the time being that is

If you desire (or even require) to run your (debug) server build on the same machine your Android Emulator runs on & a secure connection between them is required, there's only way for you: overwrite Android's default `TrustManager` with your own `DangerousTrustManager`. This allows your app to bypass *****any***** certificate verification, hence the prefix `Dangerous`.

I can't stress that enough, so again: do *****not***** use this workaround's code beyond locally running debug builds. Not on testing environments. Not on staging environments. Seriously!

Though, there's also a goodie here: this workaround allows any connection attempt using `SslStream`, e. g. `ClientWebSocket`, to succeed. Therefore, your local SignalR server's `WebSocket` transport will work as well!

##### Notes regarding code below:

1. As I enabled `Nullable` for the whole MAUI project you'll see `?` suffixes on `string`s & the like.
2. I can't stand horizontal code scrolling anywhere, hence excessive usage of line breaks.

Alright, let's get into it:

##### `MyMauiApp\Platforms\Android\DangerousTrustProvider.cs`:

```cs
#if DEBUG // Ensure this never leaves debug stages.
using Java.Net;
using Java.Security;
using Java.Security.Cert;
using Javax.Net.Ssl;

namespace MyMauiApp.Platforms.Android;

internal class DangerousTrustProvider : Provider
{
  private const string DANGEROUS_ALGORITHM = nameof(DANGEROUS_ALGORITHM);

  // NOTE: Empty ctor, i. e. without Put(), works for me as well,
  // but I'll keep it for the sake of completeness.
  public DangerousTrustProvider()
    : base(nameof(DangerousTrustProvider), 1, "Dangerous debug TrustProvider") =>
    Put(
      $"{nameof(DangerousTrustManagerFactory)}.{DANGEROUS_ALGORITHM}",
      Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(DangerousTrustManagerFactory)).Name);

  public static void Register()
  {
    if (Security.GetProvider(nameof(DangerousTrustProvider)) is null)
    {
      Security.InsertProviderAt(new DangerousTrustProvider(), 1);
      Security.SetProperty(
        $"ssl.{nameof(DangerousTrustManagerFactory)}.algorithm", DANGEROUS_ALGORITHM);
    }
  }

  public class DangerousTrustManager : X509ExtendedTrustManager
  {
    public override void CheckClientTrusted(X509Certificate[]? chain, string? authType) { }
    public override void CheckClientTrusted(X509Certificate[]? chain, string? authType,
      Socket? socket) { }
    public override void CheckClientTrusted(X509Certificate[]? chain, string? authType,
      SSLEngine? engine) { }
    public override void CheckServerTrusted(X509Certificate[]? chain, string? authType) { }
    public override void CheckServerTrusted(X509Certificate[]? chain, string? authType,
      Socket? socket) { }
    public override void CheckServerTrusted(X509Certificate[]? chain, string? authType,
      SSLEngine? engine) { }
    public override X509Certificate[] GetAcceptedIssuers() =>
      Array.Empty<X509Certificate>();
  }

  public class DangerousTrustManagerFactory : TrustManagerFactorySpi
  {
    protected override ITrustManager[] EngineGetTrustManagers() =>
      new[] { new DangerousTrustManager() };

    protected override void EngineInit(IManagerFactoryParameters? parameters) { }

    protected override void EngineInit(KeyStore? store) { }
  }
}
#endif
```

Since Android performs additional hostname verification, dynamically inheriting `AndroidMessageHandler` in order to override its internal `GetSSLHostnameVerifier` method by returning a dummy `IHostNameVerifier` is required, too.

##### `MyMauiApp\Platforms\Android\DangerousAndroidMessageHandlerEmitter.cs`:

```cs
#if DEBUG // Ensure this never leaves debug stages.
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

using Javax.Net.Ssl;
using Xamarin.Android.Net;

namespace MyMauiApp.Platforms.Android;

internal static class DangerousAndroidMessageHandlerEmitter
{
  private const string NAME = "DangerousAndroidMessageHandler";

  private static Assembly? EmittedAssembly { get; set; } = null;

  public static void Register(string handlerName = NAME, string assemblyName = NAME) =>
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
      assemblyName.Equals(args.Name)
        ? (EmittedAssembly ??= Emit(handlerName, assemblyName))
        : null;

  private static AssemblyBuilder Emit(string handlerName, string assemblyName)
  {
    var assembly = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(
      new AssemblyName(assemblyName), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
    var builder = assembly.DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName)
                          .DefineType(handlerName, TypeAttributes.Public);
    builder.SetParent(typeof(AndroidMessageHandler));
    builder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);

    var generator = builder.DefineMethod(
                             "GetSSLHostnameVerifier",
                             MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual,
                             typeof(IHostnameVerifier),
                             new[] { typeof(HttpsURLConnection) })
                           .GetILGenerator();
    generator.Emit(
      OpCodes.Call,
      typeof(DangerousHostNameVerifier)
        .GetMethod(nameof(DangerousHostNameVerifier.Create))!);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    builder.CreateType();

    return assembly;
  }

  public class DangerousHostNameVerifier : Java.Lang.Object, IHostnameVerifier
  {
    public bool Verify(string? hostname, ISSLSession? session) => true;

    public static IHostnameVerifier Create() => new DangerousHostNameVerifier();
  }
}
#endif
```

As a second last step, the newly created types need to be registered for Android MAUI debug builds.

##### `MyMauiApp\MauiProgram.cs`:

```cs
namespace MyMauiApp;

public static class MauiProgram
{
  public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
  {
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder.UseMauiApp<App>()
           .ConfigureFonts(fonts => fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular"));
    builder.Services.AddTransient(provider => new HttpClient
    {
      BaseAddress = new Uri($@"https://{(DeviceInfo.DeviceType == DeviceType.Virtual
        ? "10.0.2.2" : "localhost")}:5001/"),
      Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
    });

#if ANDROID && DEBUG
    Platforms.Android.DangerousAndroidMessageHandlerEmitter.Register();
    Platforms.Android.DangerousTrustProvider.Register();
#endif

    return builder.Build();
  }
}
```

Finally, for MAUI / Xamarin to *really* use the dynamically generated `DangerousAndroidMessageHandler`, an `AndroidHttpClientHandlerType` property inside the `MyMauiApp.csproj` file, containing ***twice*** the handler's name, is required.

##### `MyMauiApp\Platforms\Android\MyMauiApp.csproj`:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>DangerousAndroidMessageHandler, DangerousAndroidMessageHandler</AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Alternatively, setting the Android runtime environment variable `XA_HTTP_CLIENT_HANDLER_TYPE` to the same value works as well:

```yaml
XA_HTTP_CLIENT_HANDLER_TYPE=DangerousAndroidMessageHandler, DangerousAndroidMessageHandler
```

### Outro

Until the official fix arrives, remember: for the sake of this world's security, do *****not***** use this in production!

Comment: did you run into any build errors when setting the csproj property? For some reason i am getting a xamarin build error about it not being able to resolve DangerousAndroidMessageHandler. I have also tried specifying it like "Fullnamespace, AssemblyName" but that did not fix it either :/

Comment: @Dbl: You did read that it's for MAUI & not Xamarin, right?

Comment: yup. i am having this issue on MAUI. So there was no issue for you at all?

Comment: Back then: no, not a single one. Nowadays? I don't know, because I'm working for a different employer & MAUI will be done later - rebuilding the whole architecture as a Blazor WASM one is first. But again, all code above was meant as a workaround until https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/6665 gets merged (finished in April 2022) & since then, there this perfect how-to by Eilon: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/8131

Comment: 8131 discussion fixed the issue for me. Thanks! It appears the runtime does not hot swap the HttpClientHandler if it is derived from the android handler type, so the custom type is actually called. Really appreciate your reply a lot.

Answer (score 3):

In MainApplication.cs for the Android platform:

```
#if DEBUG
[Application(AllowBackup = false, Debuggable = true, UsesCleartextTraffic = true)]
#else
[Application]
#endif
public class MainApplication : MauiApplication
```

In ASP.NET Core API Program.cs:

```
#if !DEBUG
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
#endif
```

In MauiProgram.cs:

```
    #if DEBUG
        private static readonly string Base = "http://192.168.0.15";
        private static readonly string ApiBaseUrl = $"{Base}:5010/";
    #else
        private static readonly string ApiBaseUrl = "https://YOUR_APP_SERVICE.azurewebsites.net/";
    #endif

...

builder.Services.AddSingleton(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(ApiBaseUrl) });
```

In ASP.NET Core API launchSettings.json:

```
"applicationUrl": "https://*:5011;http://*:5010"
```

Answer (score 0):

If we're forced to implement classes that override the certificate verification, with emphasis on this never leaving the development environment, might as well do the bad thing... with fewer lines of code.

Just change https to http.

In the client project change the URL of your API to http and add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in **AndroidManifest.xml**.

In your server project comment out line **app.UseHttpsRedirection();**

This is terrible and I hope it will be fixed soon.

Comment: Nope, because that doesn't test the HTTPS pipeline, which you're supposed to use exclusively these days, i.e., do your best to _prevent_ any HTTP-non-TLS access.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to ignoring all certificates is to [install certificate on your dev device yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57565665/one-self-signed-cert-to-rule-them-all-chrome-android-and-ios), it will also workaround MAUI/Xamarin issue with ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback for android SSL connections. For iOS it works out of the box, for Android you need to allow app to use user certificates as described here: [How to install trusted CA certificate on Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461360/how-to-install-trusted-ca-certificate-on-android-device/22040887#22040887)

Comment: The reasoning behind your answer is just wrong - we're not ignoring _all_ certificates & besides even that, we're doing this in `DEBUG` only.