# HttpClient API calls from Maui Blazor not working with Android Emulator

Tags: .net, api, http, blazor, maui

I'm creating a mobile app with Maui Blazor for the first time (also first mobile app).  Since it's my first time I followed a tutorial where they created a minimal API which worked both with Windows Application and Android emulator for me.

Then I made a new ASP.NET Core Web API project which I want to use instead. The api-calls works in swagger and I when I run a windows application but not when I run the Android emulator where it casts an exception in the service class on the line:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{_url}/item");
```

UPDATE:
The exception is "One or more errors occurred. (java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.)"

InnerException:

- System.Net.WebException
- base: System.InvalidOperationException
- status: System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.UnknownError

Service class:

```
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
private readonly string _baseAddress;
private readonly string _url;
private readonly JsonSerializerOptions _jsonSerializerOptions;

public DataService(HttpClient httpClient)
{           
    _httpClient = httpClient;

    _baseAddress = DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android ? "http://10.0.2.2:XXXX" : "https://localhost:XXXX";
    _url = $"{_baseAddress}/api";

    _jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
    };
}

public async Task<List<Item>> GetAll()
{
    List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

    if (Connectivity.Current.NetworkAccess != NetworkAccess.Internet)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("No internet access.");
        return items;
    }

    try
    {
        // ERROR HERE
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{_url}/item");
        
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        
            items = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Item>>(content,                    _jsonSerializerOptions);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Non Http 2xx response");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
    }

    return items;
}
```

API program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Tried the following:

- Making api calls with url
- Checked network connection on the emulator
- Added CORS to my api

Since it worked before I suspect it has to do with my API but I don't know what.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: What specifically is the exception?  Have you checked that your webserver is setup to allow remote connections?  Have you checked connectivity to the server from the device (or emulator) browser?

Comment: Does the exception have an `InnerException` property? If so, what is that exception? Please paste, into question, the full text of both the original exception and the InnerException, if any.

Comment: I'm fairly new to this but I checked and my server is allowing remote connections. Checked the exception before and it said unkown. But I got this now: (java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.). Googled again and seems like i need to add cert in my network_security_config file? How do I add the required cert and where do I get the cert from?

Comment: `CertPathValidatorException` is a pretty common and well documented issue

Comment: You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71196389/19335715) about the `CertPathValidatorException` . The answer mentioned that HttpClientHandler actually uses AndroidMessageHandler as its underlying handler and he give the solution to fix this error.