# Exception in .Net MAUI App: "System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream" on Android

Tags: c#, android, exception, maui

I am currently developing a .Net MAUI application where I am making an HTTP call using a specific function. The peculiar issue I am facing is that the function works perfectly fine on Windows, but when I attempt to execute it on Android, it throws an exception:

> "System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream."

```
 public async static Task InsertParts(IEnumerable<PartDTO> partsToReport)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = GetClient())
            {
                AddAuthorizationHeader(client);
                string url = $"{Url}/endpoint";

                string jsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(partsToReport);
                HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

                if (!(response.IsSuccessStatusCode))
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Failed to insert parts: {response.ReasonPhrase}");
                }
            }
        }
```

```
 public static HttpClient GetClient()
        {
#if DEBUG
            HttpClientHandler insecureHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            insecureHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
            return new HttpClient(insecureHandler);
#else
            return new HttpClient();
#endif
        }
```

GET and DELETE works on both platforms

The Post operation like this works on both platforms

> HttpResponseMessage response = await
> client.PostAsync($"{Url}/inventory/{id}/{destination}",
> null);

but when I try to put content in the request then it does not work on android but works in Windows.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: When I hit this line " var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);"

I am calling this function in my viewmodel which has a try catch block when it hit the above line after that it goes to the catch

Comment: try
                    {
                        await DTOServices.Parts(PartsToRemake);
                        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Success", "Selected items successfully -----------", "OK");
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Error ---------------", "OK");
                    }

Comment: Is GetClient() returning the same client everytime this is being called or is it newing a new client every time, because, if it's not doing the latter, it probably should be.

Comment: It is creating a new client every time

Comment: It's bad practice to create a new HttpClient every time it's required.  just because it's disposable doesn't mean you dispose it.  Try changing your code so the HttpClient is created once and reused every time.  If that fixes your problem, then implement it in the conventional way (read the docs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed this single line from my asp.net APIapp Program.cs file **"//app.UseHttpsRedirection();"**

After removing that it worked. one of the answer by @unsane in this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71047509/trust-anchor-for-certification-path-not-found-in-a-net-maui-project-trying-t/71196389#71196389) got my solution.

Now I don't even need the Insecure handler in my HttpClient for android.

Answer (score 0):

In your project, go to `platforms` in the `Android` folder. You will find `Androidmanifest`. In the `application` tag, add `android:usescleartexttraffic` And set it to `true`.

Comment: Welcome @Mrnobody! Please try to elaborate on why one would like to enable clear text traffic for this issue