# Blazor: HTTPS certificate for local use

Tags: api, ssl, https, blazor

I created an app with Blazor (Blazor - API - DB). It's a personnal app that I will not sell.
I only use it once a year on a local network with Docker (Nginx).
I would like to secure it with HTTPS. How can I do that without buying a certificate? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any certificate authority will give you a certificate to a localhost domain, but you can generate a self-signed certificate and use that:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10176685/8792473

Your browser might complain that it's not secure since you're not a trusted CA, but you can safely ignore that for localhost purposes.

Answer (score 0):

[Generate your pfx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72988582/591285) then tell Kestrel to use it.

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(opt =>
{
    opt.ListenAnyIP(9000);
    opt.ListenAnyIP(9001, listOpt =>
    {
        listOpt.UseHttps("Path to pfx", "Password to pfx");
    });
});
```

Install CA certificates on trusted devices as described in my other answer I linked to. You shouldn't receive any warnings or need to accept any exceptions.